# Wygwam, Assets, and Image Manipulations

Tags: assets, wygwam, image

Is there a way to insert an image's "Image Manipulation" into a Wygwam field? I'm using Assets as the file manager in Wygwam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CE Image](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/basics) 'Bulk' tag may help you. It'll output the images placed within WYSIWYG editors, like Wygwam.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that'll address the ultimate issue of needing to control in-WYSIWYG image sizes. I'd still love to see a solution to accessing Image Manipulation sizes from Assets/Wygwam, though... just makes sense, y'know?

Comment: The CE Image Bulk tag did the job for me! Thanks!